# Correctly convert String array to String and back in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a following code:

```
String[] stringArray = new String[] { "One,", "Two", "Three" };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringArray));
```

which produces the following string:

```
[One,, Two, Three]
```

Right now It is impossible to convert this string back into the same `String[]` with 3 elements because of two consecutive commas `,,`

How to correctly make this conversion ?

**UPDATED**

```
Arrays.toString(stringArray)
```

is just a particular case and I'm not limited to use only this approach. I need to implement approach where conversion from String[] to String and back from String to String[] will be idempotent operation.

Comment: You cannot. Unless you have a **rule**. What is the rule?

Comment: Conversion from String[] to String and back from String to String[] must be idempotent operation

Comment: Why the superfluous cast?

Comment: Then you'll need a format that can distinguish between the separator and text. [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), for example.

Comment: @shmosel I use a dynamic types based on the user input. I'll remove the redundant  cast in my question right now

Comment: @alexanoid that's not a rule. And it cannot be true. A rule would be, "if there are two consecutive commas, ignore the second". What happens is there are three?

Comment: @BoristheSpider 
 
Conversion from String[] to String and back from String to String[] must be idempotent operation

Comment: @alexanoid you cannot distinguish between the delimiter that you have used and that same character already present in the `String`. Therefore, unless you can define a character as the delimiter that the user **cannot** enter in the `String` what you want is simply not possible. See [john's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43166053/2071828) for an alternative approach. If you insist on using `Arrays.toString`, you cannot do what you want.

Comment: @BoristheSpider how about the solution provided in john16384's answer below ?

Comment: @alexanoid if you don't care what format the `String` is in then you can also serialize to Base64. Is that the spec - that `Arrays.toString` is not required? Make that clear.

Comment: Well, if you insist on doing this with standard "toString" you could pre-process the array items with a `replaceAll(",", "\\,")` so there is no confusion, but relying on the output of `toString` for arrays sounds like a disaster waiting to happen :)

Comment: Arrays.toString is absolutely not required. I'm free to use any of them

Comment: @alexanoid then you need to completely change the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You state that "*`Arrays.toString` is absolutely not required.*"<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166009/correctly-convert-string-array-to-string-and-back-in-java#comment73406475_43166009)</sup>

I suggest you [serialize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) the Array to Base64:

```
public String serializeArray(final String[] data) {
    try (final ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         final ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(boas)) {
        oos.writeObject(data);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(boas.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Then deserialize the Base64 to an array:

```
public String[] deserializeArray(final String data) {
    try (final ByteArrayInputStream bias = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(data));
         final ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bias)) {
        return (String[]) ois.readObject();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This requires Java 8.

Example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String[] stringArray = new String[]{"One,", "Two", "Three"};
    String serialized = serializeArray(stringArray);
    String[] deserialized = deserializeArray(serialized);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringArray));
    System.out.println(serialized);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(deserialized));
}
```

Output

```
[One,, Two, Three]
rO0ABXVyABNbTGphdmEubGFuZy5TdHJpbmc7rdJW5+kde0cCAAB4cAAAAAN0AARPbmUsdAADVHdvdAAFVGhyZWU=
[One,, Two, Three]
```

Note, this works for any `Object` that `implements Serializable`, not just `String[]`.

---

As a simple alternative, you could replace `,` by `\,` before joining the array and then also replace `\,` by `,` after splitting it. This relies on the standard "escaped delimiter" pattern that CSV uses. But it will fail if the user inputs `\,` somewhere in the input, so is less robust: YMMV.

```
public String serializeArray(final String[] data) {
    return Arrays.stream(data)
            .map(s -> s.replace(",", "\\,"))
            .collect(joining(","));
}

public String[] deserializeArray(final String data) {
    return Pattern.compile("(?<!\\\\),").splitAsStream(data)
            .map(s -> s.replace("\\,", ","))
            .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Comment: Good and  it doesn't require any additional libraries.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'm going to test it in a next few mins. Thanks again for this great answer.

Answer (score 3):

Convert it to a format intended for this, like JSON.  Using Jackson it would be something like this:

```
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

 String out = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(Arrays.asList(array));
```

And back:

```
 List<String> strings = (List<String>) objectMapper.readValue(out, List.class);

 String[] array2 = strings.toArray();
```

Comment: @DineshRavi Java 1.6?!?! How is that relevant to an answer posted **9 minutes** ago? (As opposed to one posted 15 years ago, when this might be relevant).

Comment: I use Java 8 so I'm absolutely okay with this approach

Comment: You will need to include the Jackson libraries of course.

Comment: @alexanoid see my answer for an approach that doesn't require external libraries - but on the downside the serialized output is not human readable.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what you want to do, but the array separator `,` is in your string, so the simplest way to avoid this would be to avoid building the string with default array separator! like this:

```
String[] stringArray = new String[] { "One,", "Two", "Three" };
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    string.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        string.append(stringArray[i] + (i == (stringArray.length - 1) ? "" : "; "));
    }
    string.append("]");
    System.out.println(string);
    System.out.println(string.toString().substring(1, string.length() - 1).split("; "));
```

surely you can do some more stuff do get it work with default array separator, but it depends on what you want to do, I just choose the simplest way.

Comment: Anything wrong with `String.join(";", stringArray)`? Also, What if my input is `{ "One;", "Two", "Three" }`?

Comment: nothing wrong with `String.join`, and if your string can contains any characters, my solution won't work. also you could wrap every string with a character that you're sure, it won't be in the string, something like: `{"'one,'", "'two'", "'three'"}`.

Comment: Further, not sure why you use `StringBuilder` to avoid `String.concat` in a loop and then promptly use `String.concat` in a loop - you should use `append` with a `StringBuilder`...